# Div width expand/shrink on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mootools

For a site I'm making for myself and a friend, I have a div container/wrapper with 2 other divs within it: one occupies the left half and has a black background and the other occupies the right with a white background. Essentially, this lets me get a split colored background. Each div holds half of a logo. Here's the page, temporarily hosted so you guys can see it. 
http://djsbydesign.com/tempsite/index.htm

At any rate, I'd like to have links on the left and right hand sides of the page that, on click, cause their respective divs to expand from 50% to 100%. I have a few ideas, but am not sure entirely how to go about doing this (I'm rather new to javascript). The first would be to have the expanding div's z-index set to something higher than the non-expanding one, and then have it expand (somehow), and the other is to have the expanding div expand to 100% while the other shrinks to 0% at an equal rate.

The bottom line is, I have no idea how to go about doing this. I don't mind using mootools or jQuery, for the record.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
$('#left-bg, #right-bg').click(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({'width': '100%'},600).siblings().animate({'width':'0'},600);
    });
```

Albeit I'm not sure how you'd plan to bring back the the 'other' `div`.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CFNUJ/).

---

**Edited** to add a button (via jQuery) that allows both `div`s to be reverted to original dimensions:

```
$('#left-bg, #right-bg').click(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({'width': '100%'},600).siblings().animate({'width':'0'},600);
        $('<button class="show">Show all</button>')
            .appendTo('#wrapper');
    });

$('.show').live('click',
                function(){
                    $('#left-bg').animate(
                        {
                            'width': '50%'
                        },600);
                    $('#right-bg').animate(
                        {
                            'width': '50%'
                        },600);
                    $(this).remove();
                });
```

[Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CFNUJ/1/).

---

**Edited** to address the question left by OP in the comments:

> is there a way to have a page redirect after the animation completes?

Yep, just add the line `window.location.href = "http://path.to.url.com/";`

```
$('#left-bg, #right-bg').click(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({'width': '100%'},600).siblings().animate({'width':'0'},600);
        $('<button class="show">Show all</button>')
            .appendTo('#wrapper');
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/" // <-- this line redirects.
    });

$('.show').live('click',
                function(){
                    $('#left-bg').animate(
                        {
                            'width': '50%'
                        },600);
                    $('#right-bg').animate(
                        {
                            'width': '50%'
                        },600);
                    $(this).remove();
                });
```

[Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CFNUJ/3/).

---

**Edited** in response to bug report (in comments):

> The one other bug (easy fix) is that any time you click on either of the divs, it creates a new button. So say you clicked on the left half, and it expanded and filled the page, etc., and then you clicked on it again (it being anywhere on the page now). It would attempt to add a second button.

To prevent a second button being added to the `div` just add an `if`:

```
$('#left-bg, #right-bg').click(
    function(){
        if (!$('.show').length) {
            $(this).animate({'width': '100%'},600).siblings().animate({'width':'0'},600);
            $('<button class="show">Show all</button>')
                .appendTo('#wrapper');
            window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/" // <-- this line redirects.
        }
    });
```

Which, will only append a `button`, or indeed animate the `div`s, so long as the `$('.show')` selector returns **no** matches.

However if you're also redirecting to another page by clicking the button it shouldn't be an issue anyway, since none of the jQuery on the original page will exectute/be able to access the page to which the user is redirected (unless it's a page on your own domain, and you've explicitly chosen to add the same `button`).

Comment: I was thinking maybe fade-in content for that div with a back button that does the opposite of that script (i mean, the other div is still there, just with a width of 0, right?), or, for simplicity's sake, an entirely different page all in black (or white), with a button to link it back to the home page.

Comment: @Salem, see the update for one approach to bring back both `div` elements. Though presumably there's some kind of `toggle()`-based approach that'd work as well.

Comment: That may work. I'm getting a bug in jsfiddle where the divs actually go beyond the  bounds of the window and the non-clicked div still remains visible, but I'm sure that's a rendering error on jsfiddle's part. The code looks sound. 

As an ulterior method, is there a way to have a page redirect after the animation completes? (I've actually been looking for a way to do this for a while and can't seem to figure it out). I suppose you'd add a function to the end of the .click() function, but I honestly don't know.

Comment: You can add a callback (or custom function) to the animate function to have it run when it completes. See http://api.jquery.com/animate/ for the examples. Basically, you just put the new code in after the "600" in the last example David did.

Comment: Edit: It seems to work fine except for that bug, which only happens when I click on the left side. It seems to shrink the right div just small enough so that any text in the right div will still fit width-wise, and then pushes it off screen. I'll get a link up in a second.

Comment: David, this is fantastic. Not sure how I can repay you, but I owe you one. (For the record, I quasi-fixed the right div not disappearing problem by hiding the horizontal scrollbar. It works just fine now.)

Comment: The one other bug (easy fix) is that any time you click on either of the divs, it creates a new button. So say you clicked on the left half, and it expanded and filled the page, etc., and then you clicked on it again (it being anywhere on the page now). It would attempt to add a second button. I just added $('.show').remove(); before the button is drawn to fix it. Somewhat inefficient, yet fairly straightforward. Now to poke around and see if I can get a different redirect working depending on which half is clicked. [Here's what I've done.](http://djsbydesign.com/tempsite/index2.htm) )

Answer (score 0):

If you give absolute positions to your div's such that - 1st is positioned at top left corner and other is positioned at top right corner. And then in click event you can change the position of the other top corner of the div to be expanded.

You can use jquery to do this easily. Check [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for setting css.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got jQuery included, so use that! It's totes the easiest library to do simple animations with.

Here's an example click function that will slide the right background to be 100% like you said:

```
$('a#link').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#left-bg').animate({ width : '0%' }, 'slow');
  $('#right-bg').animate({ width : '100%' }, 'slow');
});
```

Obviously to go in the other direction you'd switch the width values in the object passed to the animate functions.

If you're not familiar with the animate function, check the docs, but basically you just pass CSS rules in a key : value object to it, and it'll change the CSS values over time - animating it!

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks perfect. I'd just put this in <script> tags, right? Also, is it a problem if the div shrinks to 0% even if there's a picture in it? (I'm hoping the picture will slide out with the div)

Comment: script tags would work as long as it apears after the actual HTML for the links & divs such - AKA at the bottom of the document right above the </body> tag. Also, changing the "width" property will cause a lot of text to wrap differently and such. Images, however, should slide out as long as their width is not set as a percentage value.